# reimp.exe working with TDM-GCC

Tags: mingw, gcc4.7

I use MinGW version compile by TDM that can be found [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)
Its great but I need reimp.exe to convert MS lib files (mainly MySQL C client library) to GCC .a files. Anyone have got a place I can get a working version of reimp.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sources of reimp [here](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/download.asp?path=&file=reimp_new.zip). Compiling it with my MinGW worked